# Undo unintended edit (not yet peer reviewed)

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I intended to edit my own answer to a question to append some extra info I forgot to mention but accidentally edited someone else's.

The warning that my edit would require a peer review should have been a good sign that I was doing something wrong but I didn't until it was too late.

Now I want to withdraw my edit (perhaps *fail* the peer review on purpose) since it doesn't even fit well with the rest of the answer. How can I do this?

This is the answer I accidentally edited:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/165825/177

Also, the "peer review" warning no longer appears and the answer doesn't even include my edit. Does this mean I successfully rolled back my unintended edit? Or is it simply invisible now?

Comment: It looks like your edit was rejected, it shouldn't be a big deal unless you have a track record of rejected edits that can trip the edit ban.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your edit [was rejected](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/10429) by DXM, the original author of the answer, that's why your edit is no longer visible in the answer. He left you a comment there explaining the rejection:

> The OP is asking about programming languages. These are APIs to other technologies, so I don't feel they are exactly relevant to my answer.

To see the history of your suggested edits, and whether they have been approved or rejected, go to the [activity tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/177/luiscubal?tab=activity) in your profile, and sort by [suggestions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/177/luiscubal?tab=activity). I know you realized your own mistake here, but I thought it was worth pointing out where you can find out the eventual fate of your suggested edits.

Until you get to 2,000 reputation, all your edits will need to be peer reviewed, so mistakes like this one will probably be caught, however do try to be a bit more careful in the future. Unfortunately there isn't a way to withdraw an edit, but *if* the edit had been accepted all you needed to do would be to roll it back, so that's a good enough workaround.